# strftime não funciona localmente

Tags: php

Tenho instalado localmente o PHP, Mysql e o Apache, porém estou tentando trazer os dia da semana através do código abaixo:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');

$mes = date('m', strtotime('2018-02'));
$ano = date('Y', strtotime('2018-02'));
$qtdMes = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $mes, $ano);

for($dias = 1; $dias < $qtdMes; $dias++){
    $diaSemana = utf8_encode(strftime("%A", strtotime($ano . '-' . $mes . '-' . $dias)));
echo "Dias da semana".$diaSemana;
}
```

O problema é que localmente, ele só me traz o primeiro dia e não os outros dias. Já instalei o `locales` conforme abaixo, mas de nada adiantou:

```
apt-get install locales
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

No servidor remoto funciona normalmente, mas localmente não.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver. Retirei o `utf8_encode()`, ficando dessa forma:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');

$mes = date('m', strtotime('2018-02'));
$ano = date('Y', strtotime('2018-02'));
$qtdMes = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $mes, $ano);

for($dias = 1; $dias < $qtdMes; $dias++){
    $diaSemana = strftime("%A", strtotime($ano . '-' . $mes . '-' . $dias));
echo "Dias da semana".$diaSemana;
}
```